# How can i find a specific line in a file using Perl?

Tags: string, perl

I am new to Perl. I want to find a string in some file and then i want the whole line which contains the string.

Comment: What have you tried? What works, what not? Can you open a file in Perl? Do you know regular expressions?

Comment: yes i know hot to open a file but i dont know how to search in it for a specific string (new in perl). Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`perl -ne 'print if m/whatever/' file`

Answer (score 9):

1. [Open the file](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)
2. Loop, [while](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) there are [lines to read](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) from the file

   2.1 Using [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), check if the line matches the pattern: `if ($line =~ /pattern/)`.

   2.2 If yes, [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) the string
3. [Close](http://perldoc.perl.org/function/close.html) the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( !open(LOGFILE, "<myfile.log") ) 
{
print "ERROR: failed to open myfile.log\n";}
else {   
while (<LOGFILE>){
if ($_ =~ /pattern/)
    {    print "found\n";
         break;
     }
}   
close (LOGFILE);
}
```